# How come pages on some blogging websites lack an extension

Tags: asp.net, blogs

I have been making my blog and wanted to know how come some blogs have web-address like 'www.xyz./articles/15748', while my blog have addresses such as 'www.xyz/articles/test.aspx'. I mean whether they are using some form of xml to populate their predefined webpage. If not so why is their web-page is not having any extension such as '.php' or '.htm' or '.aspx'.

Answer (score 2):

It can be done with [Url Rewriting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rewrite_engine).

For example how to use it in Asp.Net - http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/02/26/tip-trick-url-rewriting-with-asp-net.aspx

Basically it's a module that rewrites incoming url to that one that WebServer can process, and then rewrites output urls to the same as input urls

Comment: And it is very powerful... stackoverflow uses it as well, the current URL is: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21075055/how-come-pages-on-some-blogging-websites-lack-an-extension but I can change that to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21075055/zazazaza the just filter out the number 21075055 and make a friendly url of it.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the framework they are using, if they are re-writing their URL's with a module in their web server, or handling HTTP requests with a custom HTTP handler (ASP.Net).

When calling a url that is suffixed with `aspx`, that means you are requesting a physical page that exists on a server, which is then trotted through the ASP.Net runtime using the WebForms framework and delivered to your browser.

Now, if you use the MVC framework instead of the WebForms framework, then your URLs don't refer to a page, but to objects and functions. If I were to request /User/Edit/1, that URL could map to the `Edit` function on `User` object, and we would pass in `1` as an argument.

In addition, some web servers have URL Rewriting functionality that allows you to map one URL to another, so it could listen for URL's without a suffix, and transparently route the request to a physical page.

Finally, in ASP.Net at least, you can write handlers in your application that will listen for HTTP requests, and if it so chooses it could also perform some transparent routing.

These are just a few ways, there are certainly others.